# nhibernate mapping by code: Using interfaces with one to many relationships

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In fluent nhibernate, I can set up a reference to a concrete class that implements an interface like so:

```
class Address : IAddress {
...
}

class Person {
    public virtual IAddress Address {get;set;}
}

...

class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person> {
    public PersonMap() {
        References<Address>(x => x.Address).Column("AddressId");
        ...
    }
 }
```

Is there anyway to do this using in code mappings with just nhibernate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean via loquacious mappings, right? that's done like this:

```
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode;
using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Conformist;

public class PersonMapping : ClassMapping<Person>
{
    public PersonMapping()
    {
        ...

        ManyToOne(x => x.Address, map =>
                                   {
                                       map.Column("AddressId");                                           
                                       map.Class(typeof(Address));
                                   }
            );

       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something similar you can do with one to many mappings?

Comment: @Jordan yes, you can use Set(), Bag() etc... check out post by Fabio Maulo: http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.nl/2011/04/nhibernate-32-mapping-by-code_13.html